# How to create a list of lower and upper bound values based on range in Python via for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, list, math, pandas-loc

I have max range (x) that I need to create increments of and generate lists of values that increases by 1 from the previous value.

### Example of hardcoding scenerio:

```
x = 50000
max_val = 16384

id1 = pd_ID.loc[0:16384,]
id2 = pd_ID.loc[16385:32768]
id3 = pd_ID.loc[32769:49152]
id4 = pd_ID.loc[49152:50000]
```

Goal of this exercise is to replicate this above example in a more automated approach given that x changes given each account I am working through.

Below is my current approach but you see that my first value in lower bound variable starts at 1 and not 0 (which I need it to start at first row [0].

```
import math
x = 50000
increment = math.ceil(x/16384)
print("increment",increment)
for i in range(increment):
  print("i=",i)
  upper_bound = (16384 * (i+1)) if i < increment-1 else x
  lower_bound = upper_bound - 16384 + 1 if i < increment-1 else ((16384 * (i))) + 1
  print(lower_bound)
  print(upper_bound)

#####[1:16384]
#####[16385:32768]
#####[32769:49152]
#####[49152:50000]
```

### Desired output

```
#####[0:16384]
#####[16385:32768]
#####[32769:49152]
#####[49152:50000]
```

Comment: Are you aware that some_list[0:4] does not include some_list[4]? It would include only the first 4 elements, indeces 0 through 3. Having said that, are you sure your desired ranges above are not skipping items that need to be processed?

Comment: The other thing I would mention is that your first three chunks are not all the same length. Even if you fix your "starting at 1 instead of 0" issue, your first chunk will be 1 item longer than your second and third chunks. It's understood that the last chunk will most likely be shorter than the rest, but I'm guessing you want all the previous chunks to be the same size. Is this true? You may need to revamp your logic overall...

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you have a specific value that you use more than once, it's best to assign in to a variable to make your code easier to read and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something on those lines.

```
max_ = 50000

step = 16384
lower_bound = 0
upper_bound = 0
i = 0
while upper_bound < max_:
    if i != 0:
        lower_bound = upper_bound + 1
        upper_bound = lower_bound + step - 1
    else:
        upper_bound = lower_bound + step
    if upper_bound > max_:
        upper_bound = max_
    print("lower", lower_bound)
    print("upper", upper_bound)
    print()
    i += 1

lower 0
upper 16384

lower 16385
upper 32768

lower 32769
upper 49152

lower 49153
upper 50000
```

Comment: Hey RomainL. Yes - you can see that for my values output - my next lowerbound value should +1 from the previous upperbound value. That is why I did that. So desired output should be [0:16384] [16385:32768]

Comment: Ok so for your information, your range will miss some values and the first range is larger by one than the others then. I updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You can modify this as appropriate to match how you want the range start and stop to be defined. In your example output it is not consistent.

```
def create_range(upper_lim: int, range_size: int):
    current = 0
    output = []
    while current < upper_lim:
        if current + range_size > upper_lim:
            output += [range(current , upper_lim)]
        else:
            output += [range(current, (current + range_size - 1))]    
        current += range_size
    return output

create_range(50000, 16384)

[range(0, 16383),
 range(16384, 32767),
 range(32768, 49151),
 range(49152, 50000)]
```

Comment: This is seems to output correctly but is there a way to form two separate variables that represent the lower bound and upper bound values? Instead of the output since I will be feeding this into dataframe

Comment: @Dinho I'm not sure what you mean by "form two separate variables that represent the lower bound and upper bound values"? In the above solution, you can take the output from `create_range()` and use it to subset the data frame (ex. df.loc[variable_name[0]] will give you indices 0 through 16382).